# Is or-wired can bus used?

Tags: can-bus

Bosch can 2.0 specification does not clearly state that can bus is and-wired logic. ( Although every example on internet is using and-wired logic) Is or-wired logic used? If so, how can we connect a module using and-wired transceiver and that using or-wired transceiver on a can bus? How to manage arbitration in that case ?

Answer (score 1):

If you use "or-wired" logic then a '1' from any device will override a '0'.  This is just not how CAN works.

The spec defines that any '0' overrides a '1' (although they are referred to as "recessive" and "dominant" bits, they are mapped to '1' and '0' respectively).

You can't use or-wired logic.